# Tableview updates values in the twilight zone

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-data, nstableview, nstablecellview

I have followed [this tutorial](https://samwize.com/2018/12/06/guide-to-binding-nstableview-to-nsfetchedresultscontroller/) and successfully bind my `NSTableView` to a core data entity.

The table is a view based cell and is populated perfectly from the core data entity.

I have `+` and `-` buttons bind to the `NSArrayController`. When I press the plus button a new record is added to core data and appear on the table, when I select an entry and press the minus sign, that is removed from the database. For that matter I have override this code for the add/remove keys.

```
  @IBAction override func add(_ sender: (Any)?) {
    let newApp = self.newObject() as AnyObject
    newApp.setValue("New Entry", forKey: "name")
    self.addObject(newApp as Any)
  }

  @IBAction override func remove(_ sender: (Any)?) {
    // Do certain stuff before removing all selected rows
    self.remove(atArrangedObjectIndexes: self.tableView!.selectedRowIndexes)
  }
```

I made the table view cells editable. When the plus sign button is pressed a new entry is created and appear on the table with the text "New Entry". This new entry creates a core data record. Let's call it `record 1`.

Now I want the user to edit the entry with the name they want.

So I select the new cell and press enter. The cell is now on edit mode.
I type the new name I want to that cell, that will be passed to the core data entity.

I type, for example, BONOBO and press ENTER.

This table must contain just unique names. So, as soon as ENTER is pressed and the cell ends editing, I want to check core data to see if the name BONOBO is already taken and if it is, reject the name and tell the user to provide a new name.

This is the problem: as soon as I press ENTER, `record 1` changes its name instantly from `New Entry` to `BONOBO`, before I can check if the entry already exists on the database, meaning that any check I do, will always tell me that the record exists. In fact the record exists in memory because the context was not saved yet.

I am intercepting the enter press by setting the delegate of all cells to a class and using its delegate method `controlTextDidEndEditing(_ obj: Notification)`.

I have also tried to set an action for the textfields but the problem is the same.

How do I intercept it before the core data change happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick here is to leverage Key-Value Coding's built-in validation methods.  See [Object Validation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/ObjectValidation.html).

I've never done this with a managed object, but the process seems to be the same as with regular KVC validation. You want to implement a method with the name:

```
validate<Key>:error:
```

... Where 'Key' is the name of the parameter you're trying to validate. This takes in a pointer for the value you want to validate, and another for an NSError object. Inside the method you test whether the passed-in value is acceptable. You can return true to accept it, modify the value and return true to accept a revised version, or return false to reject it outright (modifying the error object to have something to send back to the user).

Comment: Warning: These methods will validate everything. Not only changes made by the user but also changes made in code.

Comment: unfortunately this is not working for the specific problem related to the question. If I insert a new record, this works but if I use the `add:` method I mention on the question, the validateForInsert or whatever is never called.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying. The `add:` routine above seems to create an empty placeholder object with the name 'New Entry'. If you've successfully added that empty object to the arrangedObjects of your arrayController it should automatically respond to KVC and call the validate routine when a user edits the name. It won't call validation on 'New Entry' because that's set before you connect it to the arrangedObjects.

Comment: If you want to validate in the above routine, then right before the `newApp.setValue()` line, add a `validateValue(_:forKey:)` statement. Sorry, I may have the swift syntax wrong — I'm used to objC — but I guess that would look something like `validateValue("New Entry":forKey:"name")`. This line explicitly invokes the `validateName()` method you created elsewhere.